# How to stop a SendKeys Injection Attack?

Tags: security, vbscript, code-injection, sendkeys

I was unsure if I should place this in security or the stackoverflow stackexchange.
Recently I was assigned to fix/debug a scripting issue. The script would automatically log users in as the administrator user. However it was observed strange things happened when users had special characters and thus they became forbidden.

So I started debugging with this knowledge, I myself being a security researcher instantly thought in the Vulnerability kind of sense (you know strange characters do strange things (XSS, SQlInjection, FormatString attack etc etc etc)).

So after seeing the code I noticed this 'vulnerability' instantly.

```
dim objShell, WshShell
Set args = WScript.Arguments
user = args.Item(0)
passwd = args.Item(1)
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
oShell.run "C:\LoginSystem\Login.exe"
objShell.sendkeys user
wscript.sleep 1000
objShell.sendkeys passwd
```

The user and passwd varibles are injectable! I could successfully get a new admin user using this and a lot of tinkering (Cntl+Esc -> Run -> cmd -> useradd).

Now I want to make sure other people (untrusted) can't do the same kinds of attacks. How can I escape or filter the sendkeys command? To make it type the %^ etc keys instead of evaluating them.

I only saw this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.71).aspx

And I can't find a way to filter this by Google. So any VbScript Guru around?

To extend the question and make the issue easier to understand:
I have to find a way to allow  this program to run it pops a window when it get launched and I need to login users with their own supplied accounts. I can use spy++ and select the boxes that way but this would mean I'd integrate C++ source code on their servers that they don't understand.

Comment: **NEVER** use this kind of script for privlege elevation. `SendKeys` alone is flaky enough, but what you have there is a disaster waiting to happen. Not only will the user be able to push other windows to the front, so that they receive the sent keys, but any user will be able to see username and password in the process list (as commandline arguments).

Comment: I agree and I first recommended this. But they want to use this anyway. All that they really want is to escape the sendkeys text to plain old text instead of commands.

Comment: Sorry, but I won't assist anyone in an attempt to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: In the unix world a lot of things are done by scripts involving privilege escalation and after that removing the privilege. It is accepted as acceptable as long as you keep the command and control (by filtering for example).

Comment: The Unix world has appropriate means to do so. What you have there is broken by design. Do not use this. Ever.

Comment: I do agree with you, completely. However the application required administrative privileges to run. And I am asked to fix the issue, so I am looking for a better solution than ('don't use app x')

Comment: You didn't provide enough information for anyone to suggest an alternative solution. All I can tell you is that the script you have is beyond repair.